# Changing default error message of mootools form validator

Tags: javascript, mootools, validation

I am using mootools in my project. For example I have an input box like below:

```
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="inputs tipz maxLength: 12 minLength:6"/>
```

My validation variable is like this:

```
new Form.Validator.Inline(regForm, {
                    errorPrefix: '',
                    useTitles: true,
                    serial: false,
                    showError: function(element) {
                        myFx = element.get('reveal');
                        myFx.set('reveal', {duration: 'long', transition: 'bounce:easeOut' });
                        myFx.reveal();
                    }
                 });
```

The problem is for the minimum length issue ; I am getting error like this:

> Please enter at least 6 characters (you entered 5 characters).

I just want to change the message like as follows:

> Enter at  least 6 chars

Is there any way to do this ?  I have used the "useTitles" also; but the problem with that is, for all types of validators (means required, minLength..etc) it has only one message.

Thanking you guys in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is defined in the mootools-more locale, eg US:

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Locale/Locale.en-US.Form.Validator.js#L24

to override it just do:

```
Locale.define('en-US', 'FormValidator', {
    minLength: "Enter at least {minLength} chars"
});
```

applicable for 1.3.2 more, locale enabled.

Comment: It worked. Will you please tell me where can I get good documentation about mootools.

Comment: pff. not sure. in this instance, it's a little more complicated than a simple doc page. you need to know of the `String.prototype.substitute` method, which is used to fill in the vars in the `{ }` from the options object. Not something you can easily document. Best documentation is on github - reading the source code. Failing that, not sure. Mootools docs are getting a complete overhaul at the moment, including of addition of user comments and user examples. Lookie-here: http://mootools.fakedarren.com/docs/Fx/Fx.Tween/fade However, in the meanwhile, what is available is what we all use. GL :)

Comment: These are the docs [String:substitute](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/String#String:substitute), [Locale:define](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Locale/Locale#Locale:define), [Locale/Form.Validator](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Locale/Form.Validator)

Comment: yeah - as separates. but you need to know how it works to get them all, there's no overview of 'when using html validator, to override messages, change locale. supported options are through string.substitute which does an object hash table replace for templating.' - hence it's hard to grasp the full picture for somebody who's unfamiliar with mootools. I believe that's the question / problem here...

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
<input type="text" id="Level" name="Level" value="set your name"/>
<!--and the message-->
<p class="comm_form" id="namemessage" style="visibility: hiden">characters allowed: A...Z and 0..9,"-","_"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

on mootools-more file, look for the line 4488:

**minLength: 'Please enter at least {minLength} characters (you entered {length} characters).',**

here you can edit the message. i think ...

regards

blady

Comment: -more is modular and even if you have something on your own build's line 4448, everyone's line numbering will differ, dependant on the plugins included. in any case, changing mootools source is a bad idea, you want to override methods or class variables / prototypes / statics via your code or you risk ending up in a situation where you cannot upgrade easily. also, look at the current codebase on github. this has been long moved into locale...